# Firebase Performance Monitoring records too few samples

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-performance

I just introduced Firebase Performance Monitoring to our app. My first testes showed me some data being recorded, so I released a version having this feature included.

Now is this app live for a couple of weeks, but the sample rate for our main service endpoint is too low. We have about ~348k sessions (GA counted sessions) per day with multiple requests to our main service endpoint. But according Firebase Performance are only ~14 samples recorded.

## My setup is

- Xcode 10.2.1
- iOS deployment target iOS 11

### Cocoapod installed Pods from Google

- pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 6.2'
- pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 6.2'
- pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.40.0'
- pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '3.17.0'
- pod 'GoogleIDFASupport', '3.14.0'

### App PLIST additions

- GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled = **false**
- FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled = **false**
- FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED = **false**

While continuing search about options I can pass to the performance monitoring I came over the page how to disable performance monitoring during app runtime. There is remote config mentioned to be used. Can this be a missing piece in my setup?

Comment: If you think that Firebase Performance Monitoring is not collecting the correct data, you should contact Firebase Support directly.  I don't think there's anything Stack Overflow can help you with, since you don't write any code for it to start collecting information.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I was trying to use the groups, but my post was not showing up. I just got the hint to ask my question over here. Code is not much. I've the PLIST file and run `FirebaseApp.configure()` that's it.

Comment: The group is moderated for first time posters.  Someone just hasn't gotten around to authorizing the post yet.  Bear in mind that it's a national holiday in the USA today and people are generally not working.

Comment: What will be the expected answer? I am not really sure this can be addressed here on SO without extensive discussion as the issue could be a myriad of things from just simply bad code to examining the wrong dataset. Performance Monitoring captures data from a number of network requests but not all. So for example, if you have custom network requests, those would not be included in the dataset. There are also issues with .configure swizzling  and some others. We would need to see the code, implementation etc. which is just too broad.

Comment: As said I just added the SDK, no additional code added for custom metrics to be recorded. I just want to see what happens while having the SDK active. What you request would to submit the whole app, what I can't do.

Comment: @ThWee - Were you able to find the solution. Even I see very few sessions but overall session is in 240K